# Who tried to sue the author of Hayate no Gotoku, and when?

Tags: hayate-no-gotoku

So apparently the author almost got sued at some point, but then the plaintiff became an anime sponsor. Anyone have any idea who it was and when this happened?

**Page 16, Chapter 470**
[image: Hayate almost got sued]

Comment: Just for info: This was on page 15 (or 16, depending on your source) of chapter 470. It is also censored in the raw Japanese version, with the same editor's note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not finding any reputable source, but according to both uncyclopedia (*caveat emptor*) and [a Japanese quiz site about anime](http://quizken.jp/quiz/!/eyJkIjoibk5NUGQwdzMrSG89In0), Hata Kenjiro, the author of Hayate no Gotoku was sued by KONAMI.

This is the quote from the quiz site, which is asking whether the fact is true or false (and true was the answer according to the quiz):

> 漫画家の畑健二郎は「疾風のごとく!」についてKONAMIから訴えられたことがある

Comment: could some one translate this ?

Comment: It states 'The Manga author HATA Kenjiro has been sued by Konami due to *Hayate no Gotoku*' ...

Comment: Any reason why he got sued by konami ?

Answer (score -1):

Well the sponsors of the anime were Geneon Entertainment, Shogakukan , P&G, Jun Planning Co., INC. and KONAMI.
So it could be one of those, but why and when? I don't know. Looks like the manga magazine covered the whole thing.

Comment: what manga magazine are you talking about?

Comment: There was a rumour it was Square Enix, but I don't have anything solid to back that up :(

Answer (score -1):

Probably Konami. The censor had 3 *'s which means three hiragana, and if it was an anime sponsor, Konami fits the bill. They did do a lot of Konami jokes, so it would be a possibility.